# Create expression dynamically

Tags: c#, lambda, fluent-migrator

Using `FluentMigrator` when i want to insert data into table i must use syntax like that:

```
Insert.IntoTable(table).InSchema(shcema).Row().Row(obj1).Row(obj2).Row(obj3)... // and so on
```

My question is, how we can build that `...Row()...` expression dynamically?

Basicly i want to mock some data in loop. How to add that `.Row()` methods dynamically to expression?

`InSchema()` method declaration looks like this :

```
public interface IInsertDataOrInSchemaSyntax : IInsertDataSyntax
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Specify the schema of the table to insert data
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="schemaName">The schema</param>
        /// <returns>The next step</returns>
        IInsertDataSyntax InSchema(string schemaName);
    }
```

And for `Row()`:

```
public interface IInsertDataSyntax : IFluentSyntax
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Specify the data to insert
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dataAsAnonymousType">An anonymous object that is used to insert data</param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// The properties are the column names and their values are the row values.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns>The next step</returns>
        IInsertDataSyntax Row(object dataAsAnonymousType);

        /// <summary>
        /// Specify the data to insert
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">The dictionary containing column name/value combinations</param>
        /// <returns>The next step</returns>
        IInsertDataSyntax Row(IDictionary<string, object> data);
    }
```

Comment: Why not use typeof(IInsertDataSyntax).InvokeMember() ? Any specific limitation to not do that?

Answer (score 0):

Could you just call Insert()... in a loop? This is what I do for inserting fake users, companies, etc.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    Insert.IntoTable("Company").InSchema("Customer").Row(new
    {
        CompanyName = $"Company {i}",
        // Other columns...
    });
}
```

You may want to look into the package Faker.Net, which will generate useful information like names, addresses, phone numbers etc.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    Insert.IntoTable("Company").InSchema("Customer").Row(new
    {
        CompanyName = Faker.Company.Name(),
        // Other columns...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this version should work.

```
            var customers = new List<object> { new { name = "Ed" }, new { name = "Edd" }, new { name = "Eddy" } };
            var insertDataSyntax = Insert.IntoTable("customers").InSchema("schemaName");
            customers.ForEach(c => insertDataSyntax.Row(c));
```

or this:

```
            var customers = new object[] { new { name = "Ed" }, new { name = "Edd" }, new { name = "Eddy" } };
            var insertDataSyntax = Insert.IntoTable("customers").InSchema("schemaName");
            customers.Aggregate(insertDataSyntax, (current, customer) => current.Row(customer));
```